# How to flash (flick) a 2d object at a certain frequency in opengl

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I need to flash two 2d object at a certain frequency. I am using for this OpenGL (glut) and C++ in Visual C++ Express Edition. OS is Windows XP Sp3, 32 bit.

I think I have successfully implemented the basic application, but I can not figure out how to make flash objects at a certain frequency. Do you have any suggestions for me? The code I've done is this.

```
void display(void) {

glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(140.0, 250.0+300.0, 0.0); //bottom left corner
    glVertex3f(140.0+300.0, 250.0+300.0, 0.0); //bottom right corner
    glVertex3f(140.0+300.0, 250.0, 0.0); //top right corner
    glVertex3f(140.0, 250.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(640.0+200.0, 250.0+300.0, 0.0); //bottom left corner
    glVertex3f(640.0+200.0+300.0, 250.0+300.0, 0.0); //bottom right corner
    glVertex3f(640.0+200.0+300.0, 250.0, 0.0); //top right corner
    glVertex3f(640.0+200.0, 250.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1280,800);
    glutGameModeString("1280x800:32@60");
    glutEnterGameMode();
    glutSetWindowTitle("OpenGL SSVEP stimulator");

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0,1280,800,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

To flash I thought of something like this (Pseudo-code):

```
int leftFrequency=12;
int rightFrequency=20;
int i=0;
while(running) {
    if(i%leftFrequency)
        blackSquare;
    }
    else {
        whiteSquare;
    }
    if(i%rightFrequency)
        blackSquare;
    }
    else {
        whiteSquare;
    }
}
```

but I do not know where to put this code. In the display() function maybe? Where can I increment the i variable? I tried to put everything inside the display() function, but the two squares do not flash. The i variable is increased up to 3. I have no type of error.

Maybe is it not correct the flickering logic?

Comment: `whiteSquare;` What is that?

Comment: Something like: draw a white square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `i` a global variable (or make it a static local) and put your flashing code (the last code snippet) into the display function.

Enable double buffering `glutInitDisplayMode(… | GLUT_DOUBLE)` and replace the `glFlush()` in display with `glutSwapBuffers()`.

Add an increment of `i` at the end of display.

Register `glutPostRedisplay` as GLUT idle function, i.e. in your `main` function before calling `glutMainLoop()`

```
glutIdleFunc(glutPostRedisplay);
```

Comment: Like this in main function?  
   `glutDisplayFunc(display);`  
   `glutIdleFunction(glutPostRedisplay);`  
   `glutMainLoop();`  
Visual C++ Express return an error: `error C3861: 'glutIdleFunction'`

Comment: @lezan: Sorry, I wrote out (muscle memory) the word "Function" in `glutIdleFunc` which truncates the word "Function". See my answer edit.

Comment: I had tried with `glutIdleFunc` when I had not found the function `glutIdleFunction`, but also with `glutIdleFunc` I get an error: `error C2664`. I am trying to search some input from google, but nothing until now. Some tips?

Comment: With `glutIdleFunct(idle);`, where `idle` is  
`void idle() { glutPostRedisplay();}`  
project compile without error. Could this be the solution?

Comment: @lezan: You can perfectly do this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be a certain frequency, then you need to flick based on time.

Comment: @lezan: Instead of incrementing `i` based on the frame number you'd increment it based on a time measurement.

Comment: @datenwolf: okei, I am working to fix it. I am using QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformaneCounter for the timing, because I need an accurate timing.

Comment: @lezan: What I mean by incrementing based on a time measurement is, that you should increment `i` everytime your time measurement accumulated to as much as what should correspond to a single `i`.

Comment: @datenwolf: I'am sorry, but I do not think that I understand exatly what you mean.  
What I was thinking of doing is something like this: http://pastebin.com/8BUGbtyK
but it does not work.